# Cannot deserialize instance

Tags: spring-boot, sqlite

I have a problem. I am using Spring Boot and sqlite3 DB. I tried to send data to the DB. 
When I sent data to the DB I have this error:

```
{
    "timestamp": "2019-02-12T12:39:40.413+0000",
    "status": 400,
    "error": "Bad Request",
    "message": "JSON parse error: Cannot deserialize instance of `com.dar.darkozmetika.models.CategoryModel` out of START_ARRAY token; nested exception is com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.exc.MismatchedInputException: Cannot deserialize instance of `com.dar.darkozmetika.models.CategoryModel` out of START_ARRAY token\n at [Source: (PushbackInputStream); line: 1, column: 1]",
    "path": "/api/cateogry/dar"
}
```

This is my controller:

```
RestController
@RequestMapping("api/cateogry/dar")
public class CategoryController {
    @Autowired
    private CategoryRepository categoryRepository;

    @GetMapping
    private List<CategoryModel> getAllCategory (){
        System.out.println("sadad");
        System.out.println("sadad" + this.categoryRepository.findAll());

        return this.categoryRepository.findAll();
    }

    @PostMapping
    @ResponseStatus(HttpStatus.OK)
    public void create(@RequestBody CategoryModel bike) {
        categoryRepository.save(bike);
    }

    @GetMapping("/{id}")
    public CategoryModel getSpecificCategory(@PathVariable("id") long id) {
        return null;//categoryRepository.getOne(id);
    }
}
```

This is my model:

```
@Entity
@JsonIgnoreProperties({ "hibernateLazyInitializer", "handler" })
public class CategoryModel {

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.AUTO)
    private Long id;

    private String categoryName;
    private String categoryDescription;
    private String imagePath;

    public Long getId() {
        return id;
    }

    public void setId(Long id) {
        this.id = id;
    }

    public String getCategoryName() {
        return categoryName;
    }
```

I sent this data from Postman:

```
[
    {
        "id": 2,
        "categoryName": "dsds",
        "categoryDescription": "sdsd",
        "imagePath": "Jsdsds"
    }
]
```

Very interesting, I can get data from the DB without problems. This is return form my DB.

```
[
    {
        "id": 1,
        "categoryName": "jeff@bikes.com",
        "categoryDescription": "Globo MTB 29 Full Suspension",
        "imagePath": "Jeff Miller"
    }
]
```

Comment: Becuase there is a problem on `Request` level. It is badly formatted hence `HTTP-400 Bad Request`.

Comment: Ok, what I can do whit this?

Answer (score 0):

Your request is not ok, you are sending an array of `CategoryModel` and the `POST api/cateogry/dar` receives just a `CategoryModel`. You should send just:

```
{
    "id": 2,
    "categoryName": "dsds",
    "categoryDescription": "sdsd",
    "imagePath": "Jsdsds"
}
```